# Passing an array as argument to a x86 function from C

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, calling-convention

I  have a bmp file and I read it in a c function and store the values of pixels as unsigned integer. I want to pass this unsigned integer array to x86 but I fail.
Here is my c code:

I have this properties:

```
extern int func(char *a);
unsigned char* image;
```

And my main method is :

```
int main(void){
  image = read_bmp("cur-03.bmp");
  int result = func(image);
  printf("\n%d\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

I check my array and it has true values.

Here is my nasm code:

```
section .text
global  func

func:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ecx , DWORD [ebp+8] ;address of *a to eax


    pop ebp
    ret

section .data
    values: TIMES   255         DB      0
```

I expect ecx to have first element of my array but instead of that I get  `1455843040` And address probably?

And here is the read_bmp:

```
unsigned char* read_bmp(char* filename)
{
    int i;
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    unsigned char info[54];
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f); // read the 54-byte header

    // extract image height and width from header
    int width = *(int*)&info[18];
    int height = *(int*)&info[22];
    int heightSign =1;
    if(height<0){
        heightSign = -1;
    }

    int size = 3 * width * abs(height);
    printf("size is %d\n",size );
    unsigned char* data = malloc(size); // allocate 3 bytes per pixel
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f); // read the rest of the data at once
    fclose(f);

    return data;
}
```

My ultimate goal is to take the elements of the array (which is in the interval of 0 - 255) and increment corresponding value in my 255 byte sized array. For example if the first element is 55 in my first array, I will increment 55th element by one in the 255-byte-sized array. So I need access to the elements of the array that I pass from c.

Comment: *An address probably?* - Yes, an array would decay to a pointer to it's first element in that context. You don't have an array though. How does the memry get allocated in read_bmp()?

Comment: Write a simple `func` in C, compile it and see what the assembler is. Use that as a template for your function.

Comment: And how do you know the size of this image?!

Comment: all images in my set has the same size

Comment: OT:  1) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `fopen()` to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` to output both you error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  2) when calling `fread()`, always compare the returned value with the 3rd parameter to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` as above

Comment: regarding: `fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f);`  one of the fields in the image header has the offset to the beginning of the pixel data.  It is not (necessarily) at the 55th byte into the image

Comment: OT: regarding: `int size = 3 * width * abs(height);`  This is making the assumption that each pixel will be 3 bytes wide.  and that there will not be any 'fill' bytes at the end of each row of pixels,   This is not (usually) a valid assumption.   Rather, the width needs to be rounded up to a multiple of 4 to get the actual number of pixels per row,  Also, There is a field in the header of the image that states the width of each pixel, in bits.  That width of each pixel can be 1, 8, 16, 24, 32

Comment: OT:  When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` to output your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a *C* prototype `extern int func(char *a);` you are passing a pointer to the character array `a` on the stack. Your assembly code does this:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov ecx , DWORD [ebp+8] ;address of *a to eax
```

*EBP+8* is a memory operand (on the stack) where the address of `a` was placed by the calling function. You ended up retrieving the pointer to `a` (1455843040) from the stack. What you need to do is further dereference the pointer to get individual elements. You could do so with code like:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov eax , DWORD [ebp+8] ; Get address of character array into EAX
mov cl, [eax]           ; Get the first byte at that address in EAX.
```

To get the second byte in the array:

```
mov cl, [eax+1]         ; Get the second byte at that address in EAX.
```

An so on.